# Multiple select in google datastore query throwing ApiError: Precondition Failed error in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-node

I'm using following query to retrieve some entities from google Datastore:

```js
var query  = datastore.createQuery(namespace,tableName);
query.select(['displayName','username']);
datastore.getEntitySet(query,function(err,data){
 if(err){
    res.status(500).end();
   }
   else{
    res.send(data);
   }
 });
```

The above code works fine if I select only one property i.e.

```js
query.select('username');
```

But with multiple select its throwing 412 'Precondition Failed' error. my entity looks like the following:
[Entity properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0UaU.png)

Comment: Only selecting a few properties from an entity implies your using a projection and your must have a supporting index.  An index is created for each individual property, but you will need to define your own indexes for projection with multiple properties

Comment: Dear @TimHoffman,
Thanks a lot for your input, I'm a beginner with Google DataStore, Could you please help me with, how to create supporting index. I'm using gcloud-node API to do Datastore operations. 

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: I'm using google compute engine (not APPEngine) and NodeJS as my runtime.

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation - every thing you need is there - https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes

Comment: Dear @TimHoffman,
I have already through the doc for which you have shared link. But I'm confused where I can find or create my  WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml file. If you can help me with this specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a multi-property index in order to use multi-property queries.

Because you are not using App Engine, these indexes need to be manually created.

I have a tutorial [here](https://github.com/thesandlord/samples/tree/master/google-cloud-datastore/interactive-demo) that covers this.

**Here are the steps:**

1. Install Java 7 Runtime (or later version) http://java.com/

   - I recommend using [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-shell/docs/) which has Java already installed and configured
2. Create a folder called WEB-INF
3. Inside that folder, you need three files:

   - [appengine-web.xml](https://github.com/thesandlord/samples/blob/master/google-cloud-datastore/interactive-demo/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml) (replace YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE with your project ID)
   - [web.xml](https://github.com/thesandlord/samples/blob/master/google-cloud-datastore/interactive-demo/WEB-INF/web.xml)
   - [datastore-indexes.xml](https://github.com/thesandlord/samples/blob/master/google-cloud-datastore/interactive-demo/WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml) (Remove the indexes I used for my sample)
4. In the datastore-indexes.xml file, you need to define your multi-property indexes. [Follow the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Datastore_About_datastore-indexes_xml).
5. Install the [gcd tool](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/downloads#tools)
6. Finally, run the gcd tool (one directory above the WEB-INF folder)

   - Linux/Mac `path/to/gcd.sh updateindexes --auth_mode=oauth2 .`
   - Windows `path/to/gcd.cmd updateindexes --auth_mode=oauth2 .`

After a few minutes, your indexes should be created.