# where to define datastore-indexes.xml in nodeJS project hosted on compute engine?

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-node

We are hosting a NodeJS application on compute engine, which connect to google DataStore using gcloud-node. 
Simple queries are running fine, but complex queries with multipple selects are giving "412: precondition failed" error. More details at":
[Multiple select in google datastore query throwing ApiError: Precondition Failed error in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928582/multiple-select-in-google-datastore-query-throwing-apierror-precondition-failed)

I understand this error is due to the fact I have not configured datastore-indexes.xml. Being a newbie in GCP world. Could you please help me where can I define my datastore-indexes.xml file inside my project.

Comment: this question is answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928582/multiple-select-in-google-datastore-query-throwing-apierror-precondition-failed

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [`gcloud preview app`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud-app#Deploying_indexes) tool with [an `index.yaml` file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/indexconfig) to specify an indexing policy.

For example, if you need an index on user and timestamp on LoginTimes:

```
indexes:
 - kind: LoginTimes
   properties:
   - name: user
   - name: timestamp
     direction: desc
```

Comment: Note that for production use, you probably want to manually update your datastore indexes rather than automatically uploading `index.yaml` each time. In particular: 1) It can take some time to update your indexes, so you probably want to upload new indexes *before* your app. 2) If you are using multiple modules, they all share the same datastore and indexes, so you probably want to keep the datastore configuration in e.g. a separate directory.